# Bound image source in Vue not displaying image

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component which is taking an object as a prop from the main App.

I want to access a property in that object which contains the url to the image source.

The url changes correctly. If, for example, the object's 'image' property is '../assets/image.png' then the src="" will point to the correct path but nothing will show.

If I put the url in the image src manually '../assets/image.png', the image displays no problem. But I want it to be dynamic.

```
<img :src="object.image" :alt='object.name'>
```

.name displays fine, but .image comes up with no image, even if the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common issue that people use Vue. The problem is that webpack does not correctly format the binded object because expression in v-bind is executed at runtime, webpack aliases at compile time, to do that you can use webpacks **require()** function

```js
methods: {
   getImgUrl(imgName) {
    return require('../assets/'+imgName)
   }
},
data () {
    return {
       object: {
          image: 'image.png'
       }
    }
}
```

In the template, you can get the image src as

```html
<div>
    <img :src="getImgUrl(object.image)" :alt="object.image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `require` to make Webpack resolved your path correctly

```
<img :src="getImage(object.image)" :alt='object.name'>

methods: {
  getImage(path) {
    return require(path)
  }
}
```