# Bound image not displaying in Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that displays an image:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="image" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    image: String
  }
}
</script>
```

When I try to use this, and bind an image path:

```
<MyComponent
    image="./assets/image-test.png">
</MyComponent>
```

But it won't display the image.

**What have I tried?**

I tried replacing the code in the component to directly reference the image. If I do the following then the image does display:

```
<img src="@/assets/image-test.png" />
```

(Only with the @ symbol)

I've tried replacing the path that's bound to the component with:

```
image="@/assets/image-test.png">
```

But that makes no difference.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089810/bound-image-source-in-vue-not-displaying-image) answer, and so tried this:

```
<div>
    <img :src="getImage(image)" />
</div>

  methods: {
    getImage(path) {
      return require(path);
    }
  }
```

Inside the component. That results in an error at runtime:

> Cannot find module './assets/image-test.png'

The full stack trace:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:217 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './assets/image-test.png'
    at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./src/components sync recursive (app.js:1080), <anonymous>:2:10)
    at Proxy.getImage (MyApp.vue?059c:17)
    at Proxy.render (MyApp.vue?059c:3)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:710)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4193)
    at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
    at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4176)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4134)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4094)
```

I also tried that with the @ symbol.

Please could someone point me in the right direction on this. I realise that there's some quirk with Vue images (it says so on the linked post), but I'm at a loss as to how to persuade it to bind the image.

Comment: Is the image already hosted on the server in the `/assets` directory? Or is this to be processed through a build pipeline such as Webpack?

Comment: It's already hosted on the server - which in this particular case is my desktop right now

Comment: Are you using webpack? Please update it in your post

Comment: or vue.config.js

Comment: Did you try to give the path of the image like `<img src="../../assets/image-test.png">` ?

Comment: @onuriltan I did try a relative path, yes

Comment: @王仁宏 I don't have a vue.config.js; however, the error does seem to relate to webpack.  I'll update the question with further details

Comment: Which version of vue are you using? Did you create the porject with vue-cli?

Comment: so, seems path problem in webpack setting, you need to know where is `@` defined or using relative path to your component, `./` means `assets` folder is beside your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image should be required in the parent component and  defined in the script section in order to be transpiled :

**Parent**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MyComponent :image="img" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    img: require("@/assets/logo.png"),
  }),
  components: { MyComponent },
};
</script>
```

**MyComponent**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  props: {
    image: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

<sup>if you place `require` in the template section you'll get an error like</sup>

> Error: /src/assets/logo.png hasn't been transpiled yet.

[image: Edit vueye-table (forked)]